# Most efficient way to insert a header in a file with large amount of data using RandomAccessFile

Tags: java, file, file-io, spring-batch

I have a output file generated as part of a program with large amount of formatted data.

I want to insert a header to this file in the first line i.e. inserting a new header line at the start of the file.

This requires pushing entire data one line down.

What is the most efficient way to acheive this through randomaccessfile ?

Comment: The same as with any other class that deals with files; you have to rewrite the entire file.

Comment: yes. But what is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: Write the header to a new file; copy the rest of the old file to the new file, using a decent buffer size; rename the old to .tmp; rename the new to old; delete the .tmp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have item number being passed as part of each item. So if the item number is one, I am creating a header line and adding that to the file in my custom item writer and then delegating the task to flat file item writer to add remaining data.

This solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any control over the file, you could write the header first (with blanks and padding) Write the file after that, finally re-write the header.  This is one way you could do this more efficiently. (Though you might end up having to leave some padding at the start of the file depending on whether you have a variable length header)